# How to force installation of nemo version 1.x and not 2.x?

Tags: 12.04, nemo

I've installed nemo as a file-manager but since version 2.0 got released, there is the problem with the desktop rendering, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358584/nemo-2-0-does-not-render-desktop-correctly-with-compiz).

How can I install the latest version of nemo before 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

The version of Nemo presently packaged for Ubuntu 13.10 is [1.8.4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/nemo). So you can simply try `sudo apt-get install nemo`. You need to remove the 2.0 version first.

Comment: But this is going to install cinnamon as well, and I think we don't want that. I only need nemo and its extras.

Comment: No, this won't install Cinnamon. I use Nemo as the main default browser in Ubuntu 13.10 with Unity and I don't have Cinnamon installed. Check the details here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/360831/downgrade-to-nautilus-3-4-from-ubuntu-13-10-nautilus-3-8/365206#365206