# How to open folders with `nemo` by clicking on folder icons on the desktop handled by nautilus or directly within nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, default-programs, mime-type, nemo

My aim is to replace `nautilus` with `nemo` from `universe` in ubuntu devel (currently vivid) using unity. I am close to this goal, after reading about [DefaultFileManager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager) from ubuntu help and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190529/how-to-completely-integrate-nemo-with-ubuntu/) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260244/make-nemo-the-default-file-browser/) question on askubuntu.com.

So far I created `.desktop` files for `nemo` in `~/.local/share/applications`:

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications 
for i in `ls nemo*desktop`; do echo -e "\n### $i\n"; cat $i; done

### nemo-autorun-software.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Name=Run Software
TryExec=nemo-autorun-software
Exec=nemo-autorun-software %u
Icon=application-x-executable
NoDisplay=true
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
MimeType=x-content/unix-software;

### nemo-connect-server.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Name=Connect to Server
TryExec=nemo-connect-server
Exec=nemo-connect-server
Icon=applications-internet
NoDisplay=true
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application

### nemo-folder-handler.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Name=Nemo File Manager
Comment=Access and organize files
Exec=nemo %U
Icon=system-file-manager
Terminal=false
NoDisplay=true
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;
MimeType=inode/directory;application/x-gnome-saved-search;

### nemo.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Name=Nemo File Manager
Comment=Access and organize files
Keywords=folder;manager;explore;disk;filesystem;
Exec=nemo %U
Icon=system-file-manager
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;FileManager;
Actions=Window;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=nemo
```

Then I set the following defaults for mime types to use `nemo.desktop` as suggested in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190529/how-to-completely-integrate-nemo-with-ubuntu/):

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

Additionally I set this value (as in [DefaultFileManager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager) about `mcterm`):

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop x-directory/normal
```

After logout and login, clicking on desktop folder icons still starts `nautilus`. Despite that, the command `xdg-open $HOME` opens the folder with `nemo` (see [here](http://www.fandigital.com/2013/01/set-nemo-default-file-manager-ubuntu.html)).

I **do not** want to ...

a) ... handle desktop icons with `nemo`, since there exist rendering problems (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358584/nemo-2-0-does-not-render-desktop-correctly-with-compiz) for example).

b) ... uninstall `nautilus` (rendering problems with nemo) or rename binaries as suggested in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260244/make-nemo-the-default-file-browser/).

c) ... use a different window manager than unity (so it is not a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190529/how-to-completely-integrate-nemo-with-ubuntu/) question, since there, Gnome is used).

So again the question:

**How to open folders with `nemo` by clicking on folder icons on the desktop handled by nautilus or directly within nautilus?**

Comment: I believe the best you'll get in this scenario is the option to open the folder with nemo via the context menu. A left click will just use the default for dir.'s which on the Desktop or within nautilus itself is obviously nautilus.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no 'open with' option. Is this what you meant? Also in preferences, you cannot select default application as for text/plain etc...

Comment: It was removed in nautilus quite some time ago & ubuntu has declined to return even though the patch is just 1 line in an area that rarely changes. I eventually gave up on my bug report & just provide patched builds. Generally don't do during dev because I have to keep rebuilding but someone inquired the other day so did so for vivid. There has been an update to nautilus since then so just uploaded another build, should be published within the hr. If inclined look here -  https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/nauty-open

Comment: Thanks, I tried your version of nautilus. It worked so far. In 'Open With'>'Other Application' it is not possible to set a default, which would solve my problem. Is there a way to implement it?

Comment: No, that's what I meant by 'the best..' The ability to changes default for inode/directory was removed from nautilus quite some time ago & rightly so, it was only useful for causing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the modified version of `nemo` (ppa [here](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/nemo)) for unity from webupd8.org (instructions [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html)).

I followed the instructions, but did not `install` but `upgrade` only:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo sed -i 's/vivid/devel/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-nemo-vivid.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then I changed `gsettings` to replace nautilus with nemo as desktop handler:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background draw-background false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true
```

Logout, login, and nemo handles desktop without rendering problems.